# ¿Cómo solucionar el error en el archivo widget_test.dart en Flutter en VSC?

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart

A la hora de realizar una aplicación me aparece un error en la carpeta "**test**" del proyecto, he intento correr el emulador para visualizar la aplicación, pero no me funciona.

[image: Error que se muestra en la términal]

Lo curioso es lo siguiente: En el error de la terminal me dice que debo revisar el archivo "**pubspec.yaml**" pero en este archivo no me aparecen errores, el error me aparece en el archivo "**widget_test.dart**".

Comment: Widget test, supongo que es la carpeta inicial que se crea al crear el proyecto, ¿No? De ser así, bórrala y ya. Es normal que dé fallo porque seguramente, hayas eliminado el código que está testeando. De todos modos, esa carpeta no influye, si no recuerdo mal en la ejecución del programa, así que seguramente, sí tengas un fallo en el archivo pubsepc. Quizás si copias el contenido del archivo aquí podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Por supuesto, el código del archivo pubspec.yaml es el siguiente:

Comment: name: app_grupo_h
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.0-403.0.dev <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
uses-material-design: true

assets:

     - assets/logo_aplicaciones.png

En la terminal el mensaje me dice que el error está es esa penúltima línea: "assets"

Comment: Ese tipo de cosas, no las pongas en un comentario, que comolica muchísimas entenderlo. Edita la pregunta original y añádelo como información extra.

Comment: Aquí te dejo un enlace con el posibles problema y solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171766/flutter-pub-expected-a-key-while-parsing-a-block-mapping-path . Puede que se deba a la identacion de alguna línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias @manuel por tu ayuda. Si, era un problema en la identación, gracias por haberte tomado el tiempo de responderme, disculpa haber respondido tan tarde.